# admob android help

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

i am having problems putting admob in the layout correctly. no matter how i put it i cant seem to see the ads at all. here are the 2 layouts...

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#0000">
<ListView
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:background="#0000"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:dividerHeight="1dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

layout2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="10dip"
android:background="#0000">
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="*"
android:background="#0000">
<TableRow>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/description"
android:padding="2dip"
android:textColor="#ffff"
android:background="#0000"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the code to the admob java is 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
already in the main layout. the problem is that it doesnt display but if i make a new project with nothing but the admob java part with the layout online i can see the ads.

and yes i have added the proper codes in the main

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

also i was told to use relative layout but that also doesnt work unless i am doing it wrong. hope someone can help!

UPDATE1:
here is the java code used by @+id/linearLayout to admob

```
    // Lookup R.layout.main 
    LinearLayout layout = 
   (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout); 
    // Create the adView 
    // Please replace MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID with your AdMob Publisher ID 
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e458091154df"); 
    // Add the adView to it 
    layout.addView(adView); 
    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad 
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest(); 
    request.setTesting(true); 
    adView.loadAd(request);
```

Comment: Is there some Java code to add the adView? As it is I can see nothing that relates to admob...

Comment: yes linearLayout is pointing to admob in the java code. this is the only working example i have found in the admob website so i stuck with it. everything seems to work in it by itself. here is the code in java....

Comment: the javacode is in update1 on the first post.

Answer (score 0):

In your main.xml add an AdView as per the example below, also don't forget to add the 
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
to the main LinearLayout definition, and replace MY_AD_UNIT_ID with your adMob publisher ID

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#0000">
  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:background="#0000"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:dividerHeight="1dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also see more examples on [this page](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html).

Comment: i get a force close. the javacode is in update1 in the first post.

Comment: please post the LogCat stack trace, there should be informations about the reason of the crash...